# "Failed to activate app" when trying to run UWP unit tests as part of a build pipeline or using vstest

Tags: unit-testing, uwp, msbuild, azure-devops, vstest

We have a UWP app with unit tests that run fine from Visual Studio. However, we are running into issues when trying to run the tests on our build agent. To isolate the issue from our build pipeline, we have tried to run the tests using `vstest.console.exe` from the command line on our local build machine. The error below is the same regardless of whether we run from the build pipeline or from the command line. We would appreciate any guidance.

> TestWindow>vstest.console.exe /Platform:x86 /Framework:FrameworkUap10
>   /InIsolation /logger:trx;LogFileName=%temp%\SampleUwpAppTest.trx
>   C:\vsts-agent_work\22\a\AppxPackages\SimpleUwpApp.Tests_1.0.0.0_x86_Test\SimpleUwpApp.Tests_1.0.0.0_x86.appx
>   Microsoft (R) Test Execution Command Line Tool Version 15.7.2
>   Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.
>
> Starting test execution, please wait... Attempting to deploy to target
>   'Local Machine'. Deployment operation succeeded, package moniker:
>   '7d25c824-2568-4449-a622-ad28662417f9_1.0.0.0_x86__a178p9x51fw8a'.
>   Attempting to launch app with app user model Id
>   '7d25c824-2568-4449-a622-ad28662417f9_a178p9x51fw8a!vstest.executionengine.universal.App' and arguments '--port 1428 --endpoint 127.0.0.1:01428 --role client
>   --parentprocessid 5744 --telemetryoptedin false'. DEP7100: **Failed to activate app**
>   '7d25c824-2568-4449-a622-ad28662417f9_a178p9x51fw8a!vstest.executionengine.universal.App' with parameters '--port 1428 --endpoint 127.0.0.1:01428 --role client
>   --parentprocessid 5744 --telemetryoptedin false'. Access is denied.
>
> **Access is denied.**
>
> App activation failed.
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.ObjectModel.TestPlatformException:
>   **Failed to initialize client proxy: could not connect to test process.** 
>   at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.CrossPlatEngine.Client.ProxyOperationManager.SetupChannel(IEnumerable`1
>   sources)    at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.CrossPlatEngine.Client.ProxyExecutionManager.StartTestRun(TestRunCriteria
>   testRunCriteria, ITestRunEventsHandler eventHandler) Closing app with
>   package full name
>   '7d25c824-2568-4449-a622-ad28662417f9_1.0.0.0_x86__a178p9x51fw8a'.
>
> Test Run Aborted.

#### Build Information

Our sample solution has two projects: SimpleUwpApp and SimpleUwpApp.Tests. The former's project file has `<AppxBundle>Always</AppxBundle>` and the latter has `<AppxBundle>Never</AppxBundle>`. The build agent is a local Windows 10 machine which we have used for UWP builds for a while. Here is a screenshot of our build configuration in Azure DevOps:

[image: Build configuration in DevOps]

Comment: What build agent do you use? I assume the Microsoft hosted agents are Windows Server,  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/hosted?view=vsts&tabs=yaml which cannot run UWP apps. You might build your own agent on a Windows 10 machine instead.

Comment: @LexLi, we are using our own local Windows 10 machine, as [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/packaging/auto-build-package-uwp-apps#select-the-right-type-of-build-agent) says is necessary for running UWP unit tests.

Answer (score 0):

You might see this error if developer mode is not enabled on the build agent.

[You can enable developer mode in the Settings app, or set the AllowDevelopmentWithoutDevLicense registry key.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/get-started/enable-your-device-for-development)

Answer (score 0):

I ran across this issue today and eventually traced it to the way in which our Self-Hosted Azure DevOps agent was running - in order to run UWP Unit Tests you have to use Interactive mode for the Agent and **not** run it as a Windows Service. From the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/test/ui-testing-considerations?view=azure-devops&tabs=mstest):

> **Visible UI testing using self-hosted Windows agents**
>
> Agents that are configured to run as service can run Selenium tests only with headless browsers. If you are not using a headless browser, or if you are running UI tests for desktop apps, Windows agents *must* be configured to run as an interactive process with auto-logon enabled.

After making this change I found the error went away.